# postgresql - check if a row contains a string without considering spaces

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to check if a row contains a string without conisdering spaces?

[image]

Suppose I have a table like the one above. I want to know if the query column contains a string that may have different consecutive number of space than the one stored or vice versa?

For example: the first row's query is *`select id, username from postgresql`*, and the one I want to know if stored in the table is:

```
select id, username 
      from   postgresql
```

That is to say the one that I want to know if exists in the table is indented differently and hence has different number of space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-matching.html); this will likely be very slow on large data set.

```
SELECT * from table 
where REGEXP_REPLACE('select id, username  from   postgresql    ', '\s+$', '') =  REGEXP_REPLACE(query, '\s+$', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would phrase this as:

```
where $str ~ replace('select id, username from postgresql', ' ', '[\s]+')
```

Note:  This assumes that your string does not have other regular expression special characters.

Comment: @ Is this the same function as  [replace(string text, from text, to text)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html)?

Comment: @mahan . . . Yes, `replace()` is `replace()`.